# Kivy development IDE for Ubuntu ( Pycharm )

Tags: python, pycharm, kivy

We have started exploring Kivy platform

We are using Jetbrains Pycharm IDE but not found way to configure Kivy in Pycharm

Can you please guide us in right direction

Thanks very much in advance

Comment: I had the exact same doubt some time ago. However i didn't find any plugin for kivy in pycharm to have some kind of graphical layout editor. If you want to simply use kivy as a normal library, at least in ubuntu, you just have to download the repository from apt-get. Use sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kivy-team/kivy to add the reposity, then update apt-get and download kivy. You should be able to use it out the box

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. We have already configured Kivy in Ubuntu. What we want when we launch Pycharm IDE then we need to have way to create new Kivy project or add Kivy files

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Ubuntu 12.04. This is how I solved it:

1. Installed CYTHON (You must do this first)
2. Installed the Python header files 
   sudo apt-get install python-dev
3. Installed KIVY 
   sudo apt-get install Python-Kivy

I want to add a very important link here: http://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-linux.html#ubuntu-12-04-with-python-2-7

Now the code builds and runs, but does not display in Python. I will edit this answer if I fix that, but this should at least get you started.

Comment: If that link is important, consider including some content from it in your question.